# jax-ws, glassfish and @HandlerChain

Tags: java, jax-ws

I write web-service using JAX-WS, netbeans 7.0 and glassfish-3.1.1.
I try to dispatch SOAPHandler on my web-service using @HandlerChain:

```
package ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import javax.jws.HandlerChain;


@WebService(serviceName = "ServerInfo", portName="ServerInfoPort")
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
public class ServerInfo {
    @WebMethod(operationName="getServerName")
    public String getServerName() 
    {
        return "test server";
    }
}
```

handler-chain.xml:

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>ws.SoapMessageHandler</handler-name>
      <handler-class>ws.SoapMessageHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
  </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

but in logs glassfish print:

```
SEVERE: component referenced from annotation symbol cannot be found
 symbol: javax.jws.HandlerChain
 location: class ws.ServerInfo
```

Help me!!! Please!

Comment: Is there any solutions for this problem? I always have to restart the GF when I re-deploy the war.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a glassfish bug: [GLASSFISH-16875](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16875)
I'am seeing the same issue, but despite the error, the service and the handler are working as expected.

Comment: I'm still facing the problem with the latest(3.1.2.2).